Typescript group modules like namespaces in C#
The issue
I work with DTO pattern and in general I use a domain-driven design, so I have many DTO, DM, types and interfaces, enums etc.
So eventually there will be a mess and it may get difficult to coordinate in the project and find everything.
I took a look at namespacing in typescript, but it didn't work as expected, that's what I tried to implement grouping:
some-test-transaction.dto.ts file:
export namespace MyExampleApi {
    export namespace Dtos {
        export namespace SomeTestTransactionDto {
            export interface Request {
                example: string;
                example2: string;
            }
            export interface Response {
                success: boolean;
            }
        }
    }
}

some-other.dto.ts file:
export namespace MyExampleApi {
    export namespace Dtos {
        export namespace SomeOtherDto {
            export interface Request {
                example2424: string;
                example24242: string;
            }
            export interface Response {
                success2424: boolean;
            }
        }
    }
}

I expect namespace merging to occur so I can access to the MyExampleApi anywhere in the project and see all the types I can use:
MyExampleApi.Dtos.SomeOtherDto.Request to get the Request dto type.
But this doesn't work, what happens instead is the last loaded file that contains the declaration for MyExampleApi overrides it and you can use only that specific namespace.
This is because javascript doesn't have native handling for namespacing like in C# so it is not possible.
On the other hand I tried to do something similar with modules and namespace:
hello.dto.ts file:
export namespace HelloDto {
    export interface Request {
        id2: number;
        name2: string;
    }

    export interface Response {
        success: boolean;
    }
}

test.dto.ts file:
export namespace TestDto {
    export interface Request {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface Response {
        success: boolean;
        data: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
            createdAt: Date;
        };
    }
}

in ./dtos directory i created index.ts:
export * from './test.dto';
export * from './hello.dto';

myapi.ts file:
import * as Dtos from './dtos';
export const MyApi = {
    Dtos,
};

I try to access something like this: MyApi.Dtos.TestDto.Request but I don't get auto-complete for the interfaces for TestDto or for HelloDto by webstorm.
What did I do wrong, and how can I get this idea to work in typescript for better organization of code?

Strongly suggest you don't use namespaces. Don't try to write C# in Javascript, but instead embrace the platform and follow conventions of that platform instead. You may be able to fix this specific problem, but you're fighting against the current.

Your directory structure is effectively your 'namespace'. Maybe consider taking a look at how other big projects structure their code.

I don't have an issue with not using namespaces at all, I am just trying to understand if there is a way to configure my structure in some way that I can group many types in one type with sub-types have auto-complete to access these types and navigate through it. I am trying to see if there is a way without fighting against it.

Because sometimes some types can have similar names, but they belong to 2 different modules. For example if I implemented a module that speaks with an external API and I have all of the types for the API, and another module which is the module that actually serves my frontend, it's dtos, dms and interface names will be very similar to the module that speaks with the external API, but not the same in its contents. I hope I am understandable

Totally understandable. In that case you have several options:  1) Use longer fully qualified names so they don't conflict. 2) Alias the names when importing. I will usually go for option 2.

The core reason this is failing is ultimately that the objects/namespaces you're exporting are fully realized values that exist in runtime, and you can't use an interface as a value on that object.

Yes, I use very long names because its the best option for myself, but many people I work with don't like it. But yea if it is not possible and its against how js works, I should close this question?

Best recommendation I can give is find an existing opinionated coding standard you like, maybe from a project that uses the same framework as you do (provided you use a framework) and follow that as close as possible. Having to make these kind of micro decisions can really suck !

@Evert Yeah I use NestJS with a design pattern (not part of nest) where controller speaks with provider, provider uses services or facades, facades are like providers that aggregates services usage but in lower levels (provider is the high level before controller), services speak to repositories, and repositories speak with the db. Its some convention I learned in a few companies I worked at and seems like it's popular. but all of them are getting messy eventually!. But thanks a lot, I'll try to find how to improve the convention or maybe find a better standard suitable for me.
